# How Parsing XML Data with PHP (Laravel Framework)

Tags: xml, laravel

**Hello Guys..
Help me parsing xml data on php..
i have xml data like it's**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DlYJ.png)

Answer (score 2):

I created a composer package that simplifies XML to array conversions.

```
composer require mtownsend/xml-to-array
```

```
$array = xml_to_array($xml);
```

Comment: Please be sure to read [Stack Overflow's self-promotion policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when referencing your own content.

Comment: @user151496: If I was a “Stack elitist” I would have just flagged it as spam. I didn’t. I notified them of the policy so they were aware of the rules to ensure their content wasn’t deleted. That said, it’s still useful for people to be aware that there is a potential bias in an answer recommending a particular package, and thus the policy.

Answer (score 1):

### You can create a helper function

https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers

```php
function xmlToArray($xml_string)
{
    $doc = @simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
    if ($doc) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
        $json = json_encode($xml);
        return json_decode($json, true);
    }
}
```

then use like `$array = xmlToArray($xmlData)`

Comment: I've tried your suggestion .. but i have "null" respon..

Comment: maybe another trik. help me bro. link xml : ' http://mandiratravel.net/response.xml ' for your try.

Comment: @lutfhiesita how your getting xml data ?

Comment: by url bro  @Kamlesh Paul

Comment: @lutfhiesita it seems your xml have some issue you can try here https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-to-json-converter.html

Comment: why did you do simplexml_load_string twice?

Comment: @TerryLin 1st one to check string can be parse or not

Comment: this is almost good, but it skips CDATA. use this line when loading the xml string instead `simplexml_load_string($xmlString, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);`